# Caller ID/Phone number from telephone line

Tags: windows, macos, api

So, I'm developing this App and I ran into a pickle. I want to be able to get the phone number that is calling. The software is going to be running on a desktop computer NOT a smart phone. The customers will be calling to a land line, so I was wondering how can this be accomplished? I just want the phone number not the name and/or other personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to do anything that deals with telephony and phone systems, etc... Your place to start at is with the TAPI API. Here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257(v=vs.85).aspx

This is actually a pretty powerful api and can be used for WAY more things than just getting a caller id.